# Convert assembly to C

Tags: c, assembly, x86

Need some help converting assembly code to C. To my understanding it is a while loop with condition (a < c) but I do not understand the body of the while loop.

```
 movl $0, -8(%ebp) # variable B is at ebp - 8
 movl $0, -4(%ebp) # variable A is at ebp - 4
 jmp .L3
.L2
 movl 8(%ebp), %eax # parameter C is at ebp + 8
 addl $2, %eax
 addl %eax, %eax
 addl %eax, -8(%ebp)
 addl $1, -4(%ebp)
 .L3
 movl -4(%ebp), %eax
 cmpl 8(%ebp), %eax
 jl .L2
```

Also explain why you did what you did, thanks.

This is what I got so far

```
int a,b = 0;

while (a < c) {
     c += 4 + 2*c;
     a++;
}
```

If I did all that correctly, then the only thing I don't understand is the line

```
addl %eax, -8(%ebp)
```

Comment: updated with what I know

Comment: @schwug - your body is wrong, but you seem to be on the right track. the first instruction moves the content of C into the "accumulator register" or AX (%eax). it then adds 2 to it. it then adds itself to itself, and then it finally (the line you were having problems with) assigns its new content to B. it then finally increments A.

so B = (C+2) * 2 --> A++. hope this helps.

Comment: Why do you need to unscramble this particular egg?

Answer (score 3):

`addl %eax, -8(%ebp)` will add the value in `eax` to the value stored at `ebp-8`. If you can understand the other add instructions then it's just the same. There's no *add 4* intruction so I don't know how you can get the expression `4 + 2*c`

```
 movl $0, -8(%ebp)   # B = 0
 movl $0, -4(%ebp)   # A = 0
 jmp .L3
.L2
 movl 8(%ebp), %eax  # eax = C
 addl $2, %eax       # eax = C + 2
 addl %eax, %eax     # eax *= 2
 addl %eax, -8(%ebp) # B += eax
 addl $1, -4(%ebp)   # A++
 .L3
 movl -4(%ebp), %eax
 cmpl 8(%ebp), %eax
 jl .L2
```

So the result is as below

```
int a, b = 0;

while (a < c) {
     b += (c + 2)*2;
     a++;
}
```

which is simply

```
int a = c, b = c*(c+2)*2;
```